# What's the difference between נכה and הרג?

Tags: words, hebrew, parashat-bereishit

In בראשית chapter/verse 4:15 and in various other places the words הכות) נכה) and הרג are used which both seem to be interchangeable in english translations.

וַיֹּ֧אמֶר ל֣וֹ יְהוָ֗ה לָכֵן֙ כָּל ־ **הֹרֵ֣ג** קַ֔יִן שִׁבְעָתַ֖יִם יֻקָּ֑ם וַיָּ֨שֶׂם יְהוָ֤ה לְקַ֙יִן֙ א֔וֹת לְבִלְתִּ֥י **הַכּוֹת** ־ אֹת֖וֹ כָּל ־ מֹצְאֽוֹ ׃

What is the *actual* or literal meaning of the two words and how do they differ? How should the text be read?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: הרג is killing to cause death, it describes the result הכות. is aa way to make this it describes the way

Comment: Have you tried checking a dictionary?

Comment: @DoubleAA I checked a lexicon and it said one meant "to crush" and hrg meant "to trample" among other sub-meanings. Seems essentially the same to me.